# CQ 5.6.1 getWorkflowSession cause Uncaught Throwable java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: session, content-management-system, workflow, aem

at com.cuso.Mao.doGet(Mao.java:97)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:508)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:356)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:254)

line 97 is just calling the WorkflowSession wf = workflowServiceObject.getWorkflowSession(jcrsessionObject);
Should I use JACKRABBIT SESSION instead of jcrSession? Which one is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar situation.There is nothing wrong with the model node that you are passing.

Getting new workflowSession from workflowService was giving nullpointer so I had to get the workflowService inside my Activator using the **getServiceReference** way and have it assigned to a static variable in a utility class.Still I got:
and following was getting logged:-

*Cannot read workflow model from node: /etc/workflow/models/deletecontent/jcr:content/model*

And there was one more "session already closed" issue. For that I again made the resolverFactory a part of my utility class using which I could get administrativeResourceResolver in my servlet.